# Wordpress plugin issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a plugin for Wordpress,  the page of the plugin is created according the following code:

```
public function menu_html()
{
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields('zero_polls') ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections('zero_polls') ?>
 <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form><?php
}
```

So above I instantiate the field name "zero_polls" which is created here:

```
public function register_settings()
{
register_setting('zero_polls', 'zero_polls_question');
register_setting('zero_polls', 'zero_polls_add');
add_settings_section('polls_section', 'Sondage', array($this, 'section_html'), 'zero_polls');
add_settings_field('zero_polls_question', "Question:", array($this, 'question_html'), 'zero_polls', 'polls_section');
add_settings_field('zero_polls_add', 'Add a new answer:', array($this, 'add_html'), 'zero_polls', 'polls_section');
}
```

And the menu_html function is called when Wordpress update the menu with:

```
public function add_admin_menu()
{
    $hook = add_submenu_page('options-general.php', 'Sondages', 'Sondages', 'manage_options', 'zero_polls', array($this, 'menu_html'));
    add_action('load-'.$hook, array($this, 'process_action'));
}
```

As you can see above, I added an action which redirect `process_action()` function here:

```
function process_action(){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_poll_options(id, label) VALUES('','YOUPI')");
}
```

The problem is that my table wp_poll_options does not get update after I submit the form (YOUPI does not appears).
I think I missing something in the understanding of the Wordpress workflow, please help, thank you.

Comment: Use `$wpdb->last_query` to debug and see where it is getting stuck.

Comment: Should the **id** be being set as **''**? Shouldn't it be a **primary_key** and **auto incrementing**?

Comment: @DanWhite it auto incrementing, so leaving a blank should work

Comment: blank != **''**

Comment: If it is auto incremented, shouldn't it just be emitted, also for security sakes?

Comment: Set WP_DEBUG true in wp-config, and check the error.